# Learning python, function with a loop question

Tags: python, function, loops

I'm currently learning python in a Zybooks interactive eText and need someone to help me understand why this isn't working.  Zybooks tests a few different iterations of your code and this one is working for three and failing on their fourth test.  They don't actually tell you what they are testing until you run the code...  Any help understanding where I'm going wrong is appreciated.

Write a function shampoo_instructions() with parameter num_cycles. If num_cycles is less than 1, print "Too few.". If more than 4, print "Too many.". Else, print "N : Lather and rinse." num_cycles times, where N is the cycle number, followed by "Done.". Sample output for the given program:
1 : Lather and rinse.
2 : Lather and rinse.
Done.

Here is what I wrote that works for three of the five tests...

```
def shampoo_instructions(num_cycles):
    if num_cycles < 1:
        print('Too few.')
    if num_cycles > 4:
        print('Too many.')
    else:
        N = 0
        while N < num_cycles:
            print(N+1, ': Lather and rinse.')
            N = N + 1
        print('Done.')

shampoo_instructions(2) #this cannot be changed in the exercise
```

Comment: Test your code with `num_cycles=0`. What do you see?

Comment: I did try changing the 1 to a zero and had the same result, test four still failed because Done was added.

Comment: You misunderstood my statement. I suggested calling your function passing `0` as the argument and observe the output, i.e. `shampoo_instructions(0)`.

Comment: Sorry, still learning...  The final line is not available for edit, it is part of the code they give you that you cannot change.

Comment: You don't have to use their environment; you can use any Python interpreter, or something like https://repl.it/languages/python3 . Once you debugged your solution you can paste it back to their system.

Comment: Please read my comments more carefully. I was suggesting you to debug your code in another environment to find and fix the bug you currently have. Their platform is to submit answers, not necessarily to develop and debug them. Also see the question marked as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: OK, thanks.  Sorry if I'm frustrating you, again, I'm learning.  I guess it's hard to debug something you don't understand being wrong.  I appreciate the help you've provided.

Comment: All good. As I said, try running it somewhere else with different parameters to see what's wrong.